# Google App Engine is not creating table (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, models

I have this model

```
class SiteUser(db.Model):
    site_user = db.UserProperty()
    total_votes = db.IntegerProperty(default=1)
    liked_items = db.StringProperty()

class Item(db.Model):
    user_who_liked_this_item = db.UserProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()
    url = db.StringProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)   
    points = db.IntegerProperty(default=1)
```

`Item` table is created but `SiteUser` table is not created. Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Thanks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no 'tables' on App Engine. A kind will show up in the datastore viewer if you have inserted at least one record with that kind; my guess is that you haven't inserted any `SiteUser` entities into the datastore.

Answer (score 2):

When you use this the first time it will "create a table"

```
new_user = SiteUser()
new_user.liked_items = str(42)
new_user.put()
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot Create a entity in admin console, Unless until there is atleast one record of that entity created programtically